# Minecraft Forge Getting Required ItemStacks for IRecipe

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I'm working on a mod for Minecraft 1.10.2 and I'm trying to get the input `ItemStack` array out of the `IRecipe` interface.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below should handle most Recipes, but not all. If you need more, I can write more.

```
     /**
     * Determines the input of a IRecipe.
     * This method handles most of the IRecipes, but not all of them.
     * @param Item
     * @return Null if not handled.
     */
    private List<ItemStack> Test(IRecipe Item)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Item instanceof ShapelessRecipes)
            {
                ShapelessRecipes a = (ShapelessRecipes)Item;
                return a.recipeItems;
            }

            if (Item instanceof ShapedRecipes)
            {
                ShapedRecipes a = (ShapedRecipes)Item;
                return Arrays.asList(a.recipeItems);
            }

            if (Item instanceof ShapedOreRecipe)
            {
                ShapedOreRecipe a = (ShapedOreRecipe)Item;

                ItemStack Item2;
                NonNullList<ItemStack> Item1 = NonNullList.create();

                for (Object b: a.getInput())
                {
                    if (b instanceof ItemStack)
                    {
                        Item2 = (ItemStack)b;
                        Item1.add(Item2);
                    }

                    if (b instanceof NonNullList)
                    {
                        NonNullList<ItemStack> NonNull1 = (NonNullList<ItemStack>)b;
                        Item1.addAll(NonNull1);
                    }   

                    return Item1;
                }
            }

            if (Item instanceof ShapelessOreRecipe)
            {
                ShapelessOreRecipe a = (ShapelessOreRecipe)Item;

                ItemStack Item2;
                NonNullList<ItemStack> Item1 = NonNullList.create();

                for (Object b: a.getInput())
                {
                    if (b instanceof ItemStack)
                    {
                        Item2 = (ItemStack)b;
                        Item1.add(Item2);
                    }

                    if (b instanceof NonNullList)
                    {
                        NonNullList<ItemStack> NonNull1 = (NonNullList<ItemStack>)b;
                        Item1.addAll(NonNull1);
                    }   
                }

                return Item1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Handle the error
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: thank you, but there is still the problem with the custom `IRecipe` classes

Comment: Or are you referring to someone who creates their own recipe that implements IRecipe?

Comment: yes, but also the vanilla ones: http://prntscr.com/fp6p2y from the `CraftingManager` class

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry. I have the code kind of implemented, but it is all scattered in one of my own mods. Let me try and find it.

Comment: Added support for 2 more types. I think you should be supported for all the standard ones. As for custom ones, there is no way to reliably get the input automatically. I spent a month trying to figure it out. If someone has a non supported one, just log that it exists. When you get some time, pop open your debugger and see what the type is, then do like I did and handle that IRecipe specifically. Good luck.